# Functionscope and Callbacks in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i have to calculate some `share` in a loop. In every iteration of that loop i have to get a variable called `rent` from an array. So i devided the `calculate` function from the database stuff.

```
var calculate = function() {
    while(count < 100) {
        var share = 50;
        var shareArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            var pension = share*2; // mathematical stuff
            // Gets a rent from a database and returns it in a callback
            getRent(modules, share, function(rent) {
                share = rent*foo; // some fancy mathematical stuff going on here
                // I need to get the share variable above out of its function scope
            });
                    // I need the share variable right here
            shareArray.push(share);     // the value of share will be for i = 0: 50, i= 1: 50 ...
                                        // This is not what i want, i need the share value from getRent()
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Now as you may see i am presented with the following trouble. Because I'm working in node.js, the only way to get the `rent` variable from the modules array is through this callback function called `getRent()`. The thing is, i need the `share` value after this step but outside of `getRent()`.
Is there any way i can do this?

This is the `getRent()` - Function:

```
var getRent = function(modules, share, callback) {
        // Searching for a fitting rent in the modules array
        // Just assume this is happening here
        callback(rent);
};
```

So the question is: How can i "return" `share`:

```
getRent(modules, share, function(rent) {
                    share = rent*foo; // some fancy mathematical stuff going on here
                    // I need to get the share variable above out of its function scope
});
```

in any way?

Comment: What does "getFromDB()" look like?  I don't understand how that can work, since fetching from a database almost certainly involves an asynchronous step too.

Comment: Also you'd almost certainly be much better off, performance-wise, if you could do **one** query to get all the values you need, rather than a separate query for each one. It's going to be much, much slower to do it one at a time.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is just a constructed example. The real code would be way to difficult to explain this. Just assume this works. Mhh maybee i'll edit it.

Comment: Well the basic issue is that with an asynchronous system, you kind-of have to turn your logic inside-out.

Comment: Does this mean, that it is not possible to get share out of that function scope?

Comment: @Shanimal that won't work if it's an asynchronous system (which it probably is).  Think about how it works: in an asynchronous system, the callback is called *after* (usually *long* after) the function you passed it to has returned!  How can `return` possibly work?

Comment: no i got that after i posted that knee jerk wtf. sorry about that

Comment: No, this wouldn't work because if getRent is to slow the algorithm would increment again before share has returned. This is because of node.js non-blocking style, isn't it?

Comment: yeah there is, you just create a variable and then set that instead of setting share in the getRent callback.

Comment: Is there really no "function() - return" pattern possible? What is the right approach on invoking functions in loops in node.js?

Comment: there is, its called a "promise" or "future", and you use commJS see also requireJs to return async objects that aren't built already... but more generically when you're programming javascript you just know how to get around this. its part of why closures are so widely used everywhere. do this and call this when your done is the whole point of a closure. its why the code calls it a "callback" i.e. call me when you're done. also don't forget that scope isn't just local, it chains outward through the closures

Answer (score 1):

If `getRent` is async there's no way to get the result synchronously. Fundamentally you don't know the value that `getRent` will end up supplying to its callback until it finally returns it. So it isn't a question of function scope, its a question of timing. You just have to wait for `getRent` to do its thing before you can get the value for `rent`. You need to refactor your code so that `calculate` is also async.

Something like:

```
// Refactor calculate to be async:
function calculate(cb) {
    var data = [];
    for ( var i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
        getRent(function (rent) {
            data.push(rent);
            if ( data.length === 100 ) cb(data);
        });
    }
}

// And then use it async:
calculate(function (data) {
    // data array arrives here with 100 elements
});
```

The above answer is perhaps similar to how you might achieve it with vanilla JS. Using the `async` library like miggs suggests is probably a good idea in the long run. But like I said, if you use vanilla JS, or the `async` lib, there's no getting away from the fact that you'll have to refactor towards asynchronicity both in this code and the code that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) method of the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library (`npm install async`) to simplify this:

```
var count = 0;
var shareArray = [];

async.whilst(
    function () { 
        return count < 100; 
    },
    function (next) {
        count++;
        getRent(function(rent) {
            // What does modules do anyway??
            // Dont know where foo comes from...
            shareArray.push(rent*foo); // some fancy mathematical stuff going on here
            next();
        });
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(shareArray);
        // Do sth. with shareArray
    }
);
```

If it was OK for you to request all 100 call in parallel, you could also use the [`parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) function.